# React App Long running ajax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

We have a React Redux app which requires long running ajax to show its main content.

Consider for Example showing list of some items, and fetching that list requires 1-2 seconds.

Currently i have put the ajax call in the componentDidMount of the listing component. but i can see the call takes around 500-900 millis before starting. This adds up to Backend latency not creating very favourable experience.

We want the Ajax call to be triggered as early as possible. I have thought of triggering my ajax in index.js or public index.html and storing the result in window variable later in componentDidMount i will read it, But my solution sounds more like a hack to me can anyone recommend anything better?

Comment: Why not do it before the component renders and store the response in your state? Without seeing how your app is structured it's difficult to provide an answer

Comment: i wouldn't consider it a hack to pre-load data when your app loads if you want the view to load instantaneously.  you don't need to store it in a window variable, just store it in redux as if you had called it in componentDidMount.

Comment: fetch your data in `componentDidMount` of very top component of your application and store results anywhere you want (state or redux store or smth), it's the fastest way you can use with React without any dirty hacks

Comment: while using connect method and passing entire actions as object as dispatch argument (import * as actions from './actions') . I got so caught up that i even forgot that i can dispatch actions on the store anywhere i want. Thanks Guys for reminding the basics again :) . I will surely try  to dispatch my ajax call actions earlier in the loading process.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the call in the constructor of the component. There is also a lifecycle method called `componentWillMount` that you can use. Both these methods will start the ajax call before the component is mounted. It might be worth it if it is a large component that you mount.

On the other hand, if your delay comes simply from downloading and parsing the javascript code, it is harder to optimize. Then I would recommend checking out server-side rendering or code splitting. But those solutions will take quite some time to implement.

Comment: `componentWillMount` should not be used for side effected function calls. (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount)